# Get Selected Index of List of Items in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a sheet with dropdowns created using 'Data->Validation->List of Items which control what the user can input into these cells.

Once a user selects an item from a dropdown, is it possible to get the index value of the item selected?  If so, how?

The ultimate goal of this question is to have formulae which translate textual information into number data via CHOOSE()

Example

A1 = Data->Validation->List of Items -> None,Apple,Orange,Banana

A2 = CHOOSE(A1,0,1.5,2.3,1.8)

User selects 'Orange' then A2 = 2.3

Obviously the above fails as CHOOSE(A1... results in an error as 'Orange' is passed, not the index value of Orange

Comment: Creating separate named ranges is viable, however, it's messy and cumbersome & would require rewriting the entire spreadsheet which was done using 'List of items' not ranges.  VLOOKUP is not appropriate in this case because 'List of Items' is a 1 cell lookup - it will always return the same cell information.  Presumably when 'List of Items' are created they are done as an array [0][None][1][Apple] and so on.  When a user selects one it returns the string but Sheets provides no way that I can find to access the index

Answer (score 4):

It seems possible that what you want is:

```
=Choose(Match(A1,{"None","Apples","Oranges","Pears"},0),0,1.5,2.3,1.8)
```

or something very similar.

Comment: I guess that does work, it just means duplicating 100% of data in the match which is just as ugly as nested IFs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I really do appreciate the help, I think it's a case of a poorly implemented feature that was never flushed out properly.  Info testing it I found when you create a 'List of Items' in that way the data kind of goes no where so can't be interacted with by anyone but the user other than to return the selected item's value as a string.  I've found it's pretty much a case of having to rewrite the data into ranges to get the same user implementation and be able to manipulate the data properly.

Comment: What I think it's doing (without code tracing) is just taking whatever you enter in your list of items box and running a specific set of code to create the dropbox bypassing any array or range creation step for the sheet to interact with.

Comment: Unfortunately for my use case scripts are forboden :(